# Best way to store database login credentials for a PHP web pages

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to make a php application which can connect to MySQL database.

Currently I am storing BOTH the database connection details in a `connection.php` which has a class declared in it, this class is responsible for all the database connection.

```
<?php
     $username = "veer";
     $password = "tiger";
?>
```

Whichever page I need to make a Database connection, I use `include_once('connection.php')`, which makes my database connection and then I proceed with normal `php` and `mysql` coding.

This way if there are other developers, then they can also use the same way and go for the `DB` interaction, without knowing what is written in `connection.php`.

Is this a safe approach? Is there any better / alternative approach for storing DB credentials?

Can someone use this:

```
<?php
include_once('http://www.abc.com/connection.php');
echo($username.' '.$password);
?>
```

to get the username and password? Is this feasible.

Comment: no, your `include_once` example wont work. but you should be storing this outside your web root anyway.

Comment: "This way if there are other developers, then they can also use the same way and go for the DB interaction, without knowing what is written in connection.php." Wrong. If they can add code they can read whatever is in there.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "safe"? Safe against what?

Comment: Are you storing username and password to another website?

Comment: There is another way. You can "allow" the data to have values only if the session is existing.

Comment: @Prisoner: I din't get you. Where should I place this file.? I place it with the remaining php files that a user can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used some frameworks like  Yii, CodeIgniter and Django and all of them store the database connection in a file in plain text. For example in Yii is under protected/config/main.php. So theoretically it is safe to store your credentials this way. Of course you can take more measures like Yii that use an .htaccess to deny all access to the protected folder (hence the name protected)

In an ideal world only you (and your co-workers) have access to this file.

Answer (score -1):

Safe way? Obfuscate the db username and password. The disadvantage is obvious.

Answer (score -4):

If developer can include that file he can read it and find out your MySQL connection details.
So it's better to store your MySQL connection details in different file.

Create new file config.php with your db credentials. And then include whatever you need.

Example:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
include_once('http://www.abc.com/connection.php');
echo($username.' '.$password);
?>
```